# Where can i find the source code of tf::StampedTransform class and function

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have downloaded the **tf** sourcecode package but can not find the sorce code of tf::StampedTransform class. I want to see the sourcecode of the **getRPY** function in the example code as below:

```
tf::StampedTransform transform;
tfListener.lookupTransform(source_frameid, target_frameid, ros::Time(), transform);
double yaw, pitch, roll;
transform.getBasis().getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
```

Can any body give me some hint?
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217778/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-tf::stampedtransform-class-and-function/) by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`tf::StampedTransform` is derived from `tf::Transform` (see implementation of `tf::StampedTransform` [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/transform__datatypes_8h_source.html#l00081) and the docs of `tf::Transform` [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transform.html)).

`getRPY` is actually not a function of any of those clases, but of the `Matrix3x3` Type, which is a member of `tf::Transform` that you get via the `getBasis()` function. The docs of `Matrix3x3` can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Matrix3x3.html).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-09-18**:
Thanks a lot!

Is there a easier way to tranform Quaternion to EulerAngle besides *getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw)* in ROS?